# How should new factor levels not present in the model test data be handled?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

Let's say I am predicting something using a linear model and have data for the past 11 months only, and I need to predict the following month. I train the model with months as dummy variables in the data among other unrelated variables, because the model will be updated in the future as more data becomes available, and the month has a big effect on the dependent variable. So the dependent variable needs to be predicted, but the dummy variable for that month is missing.

Does it make sense to in the test data set each of the month dummy variables to have a value of 1/11, so that the value for the predicted month would be considered to have the same effect on the predicted value as the average month?

Comment: Why not add the missing level from the start?

Comment: I was using months just as an example, but what if there are lots of missing levels?

Comment: Then you are proverbially screwed. You could add just one levels which is "other".